# PostgreSQL Date Type Conversion Issue when Calling through Hibernate Query

Tags: java, hibernate

```
select * 
from commanconfig.fn_cm_get_usage_statistics_progress(422,'1-nov-2019','27-nov-2019')
```

The above query is working fine.

But when I am calling the function through Hibernate its showing error:-

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function 
property.fn_pt_assessment_register_report(integer, 
unknown, unknown) does not exist
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type 
casts.
```

Hibernate Code is:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    StoredProcedureQuery query = session
                .createStoredProcedureQuery("property.fn_pt_assessment_register_report")
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, java.util.Date.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter(3, java.util.Date.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                .setParameter(1, (int)qryprm.get("ULBID"))
                .setParameter(2, ((java.util.Date)qryprm.get("FROMDATE")))
                .setParameter(3, ((java.util.Date)qryprm.get("TODATE")));
           Boolean b = query.execute();
            return query.getResultList();
```

Conversion of Date formats:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    try {
        qryprm.put("FROMDATE", (sdf.parse((String)qryprm.get("FROMDATE"))));
        qryprm.put("TODATE", (sdf.parse((String)qryprm.get("TODATE"))));
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use a NativeQuery with parameters? There is no need to use `createStoredProcedure()`

Comment: where is the hibernate error occuring? In query.execute?

Comment: Thank you ... It was resolved by Native Query ..

Answer (score 0):

Probably your date is not completely correct because JSF add hour time to dates. Try to format with new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").In this case I use 'dd/MM/YYYY' because my dateStyle is European, you must adjust to yours.